# How to enable memory compression on SLES12.2?

Tags: memory, compression, suse

I can read the:

https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/12-SP2/#fate-318957

that it can be enabled with a:

```
echo Y > /sys/module/zswap/parameters/enabled
```

**Q:** but how to make it permanent? Cannot find any official DOCs for it, only random blogs, which is not enough imho :) Or everybody have to write their own systemd unit to make it permanent, across reboots?

Answer (score 1):

It's in the SLES 12 [release notes](https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/12/#fate-315454).

> Starting with SLES 12, you can enable the zswap driver using the boot parameter zswap.enabled=1. The zswap driver inserts itself between the system and the swap hard drive, and instead of writing memory to a hard drive, it compresses memory. This speeds up both writing to swap and reading from swap, which results in better overall system performance while using swap.

Summed up:

```
yast2 bootloader
```

...and add "zswap.enabled=1" to the Optional Kernel Command Line Parameter in the Kernel Parameters tab.